# With Rails, how to convert code which used Facebooker to using Facebooker2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, facebooker, facebooker2

There is code to use Facebooker gem (which uses the old Facebook REST API).  Does someone have experience how to convert those code to
using Facebooker2, which uses the new Facebook Graph API?

For example, Facebooker has `Facebooker::Session` and `Facebooker::User` and they are both gone in Facebooker2.

I can't find too much docs on the two sets of API.

Answer (score 0):

I've written an article about converting your Facebooker app to Facebooker2.  This also means that should change from FBML to iFrame if you haven't already:

http://www.clickonchris.com/2010/11/facebooker-converting-from-fbml-to-iframe/